# All statement of python classes executing without object creation

Tags: python

I am new to python and just created 3 classes in a module i.e global scope, inside a function and if block. while running the module, all statement of all the classes are running. I am surprised why all classes are got executed without any object created.

```
class Demo:
    print('global class Demo')

def test():
    print('Demo')
    class Demo:
        x = 'Demo from fuction test()'
        print(x)

test()

if True:
    class Demo:
        print('Demo from if:')
```

Comment: You are just declaring the class thrice, without any object creation. What is it you are tryingt o do here?

Comment: What is the thing you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: trying to understand how to declare and run a class. As I have got to know you can declare a class in different scope. https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#a-first-look-at-classes

Answer (score 2):

When you write a block of code of this form:

```
class Name:
    <statements>
```

Python always runs the `<statements>`, right then and there. The main difference is that, if any of those statements define variables, the variables are not set in the global namespace; instead they are "scooped up" and saved in a dictionary, which is associated with an object called (in this case) `Name`.

For example, you know how this works:

```
a = 1
print(a) # prints 1
```

You can stick that inside a class definition and it still does the same thing:

```
class Name1:
    a = 2
    print(a) # prints 2
```

but after the class definition ends, the variable `a` is "scooped up" and no longer has the value it had inside the class definition.

```
a = 1
print(a) # prints 1

class Name2:
    a = 3
    print(a) # prints 3

print(a) # prints 1
print(Name2) # prints <class '__main__.Name2'>

print(Name2.a) # prints 3; this shows where the `a` from the class definition went
```

You might be mixing this up with a *function* definition. When you start a function definition block using the `def` keyword, the statements inside the block are *not* executed at that time.

```
def func():
    a = 4
    print(a)

# this prints nothing unless you call func()
```

They're saved until later, when you call the function. But classes are not like functions in this way.

Comment: You are correct, I mixed up function definition. Thanks! Devid.

Comment: @DJ- If my post answered your question, I'd encourage you to indicate that by accepting it - click the green checkmark to the left of the post.

Comment: Great answer. Python is so full of magic. I never expect an statement could be executed in a class body.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#class-definitions):

> A class definition is an executable statement.

and...

> The class’s suite is then executed in a new execution frame (see
>   Naming and binding), using a newly created local namespace and the
>   original global namespace. (Usually, the suite contains mostly
>   function definitions.) When the class’s suite finishes execution, its
>   execution frame is discarded but its local namespace is saved. [4] A
>   class object is then created using the inheritance list for the base
>   classes and the saved local namespace for the attribute dictionary.
>   The class name is bound to this class object in the original local
>   namespace.

Comment: This(A class definition is an executable statement) helps to understand the concept. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what you're asking, but defining a class is not the same as creating an object. You need to call the class to create an instance (the object you're looking for).

```
# The class (a type)
class Demo:
    pass

# An instance of the class (an object)
Demo()
```